# Map javascript array from specific value to be a new key

Tags: javascript, lodash

so i have this kind of array

```
columnData:[
 {
   title: 'Male Members',
   key: 'm_members'
 }
 {
   title: 'Female Members',
   key: 'f_members'
 }
]
```

and i want to turn it into something like this

```
newColumn: {
  m_members: 'Male Members',
  f_members: 'Female Members
}
```

how to do that with javascript or with lodash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the items with the  `forEach` method then fill a new object with the `key` and `value` obtained from `columnData`:

```js
const columnData = [{title: 'Male Members',key: 'm_members'},{title: 'Female Members',key: 'f_members'}]

let newData = {};
columnData.forEach(e => {
  newData[e.key] = e.title
})

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: wow this is the most simple approach that even me a beginner on the array thing can quickly understand

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var columnData = [{title: 'Male Members',key: 'm_members'},{title:'Female Members',key: 'f_members'}];
newColumn = columnData.reduce((a,{title, key}) => Object.assign(a, {[key]:title}),{});
console.log(newColumn);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `Object.assign` and spread syntax `...`.

```js
const data = [{title: 'Male Members',key: 'm_members'}, {title: 'Female Members',key: 'f_members'}]

const result = Object.assign({}, ...data.map(({title, key}) => ({[key]: title})));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = {};

for(const {title, key} of columnData)
  result[key] = title;
```

A simple for loop does it.